# Where to ask for advice to configure a new PC?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I want to ask for advice for specific computer components (Graphic card, processor, motherboard ...) to build a new PC for my purposes. Is there any Stack Exchange site where I can get help with it? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Yep, it's called Toms Hardware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recommendation requests are **off-topic** on (almost all) Stack Exchange sites, as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

We *do* have a [Hardware Recommendations](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) community, but they have very strict [requirements](https://hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/206/4495) about what kind of requests are accepted. They do both requests for complete PCs (e.g. [this one](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/6224/4495)) and for individual parts (e.g. [this one](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/1347/4495)).

Comment: Thanks! I guess that the first one could be really helpful for me. Elsewhere, maybe a forum would be more appropriated for it? Thanks for the answer! @Glorfindel

Comment: Yes, for open ended questions you're better off at Quora or Reddit.